# How to find the range of week, month and year for current Date and Time in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I get start and end range of weeks, month and year in android ?

say for current Date and time 18,Feb,2022
I want some thing like,

week -> 14-01-2022 to 20-02-2022

month -> 01-01-2022 to 28-02-2022 ( likewise 30, 31 for other months )

year -> 01-01-2022 to 31-12-2022

Answer in kotlin code is preferable please

Comment: One option would be to use `java.time`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Here's an example for the week rage

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.util.Locale
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.TimeZone
import java.util.Calendar

val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                      

fun toCalendar(date: Date): Calendar {
    val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())
    cal.time = date
    return cal
}

fun printRange(date: Date, rangeType: Int) {
    val cal: Calendar = toCalendar(date)

    val startDay = cal.getActualMinimum(rangeType)
    cal.set(rangeType, startDay)
    val startDate = cal.time
    
    val endDay = cal.getActualMaximum(rangeType)
    cal.set(rangeType, endDay)
    val endDate = cal.time
        
    println("${formatter.format(startDate)} to ${formatter.format(endDate)}")
}


fun main() {
    printRange(Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    printRange(Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    printRange(Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
}
```

Result :

```
20-02-2022 to 26-02-2022
01-02-2022 to 28-02-2022
01-01-2022 to 31-12-2022
```

You can do the same logic for other range (month and year).

Please, pay attention to the [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) when working with dates!

Comment: ok. pl. guide me how do I get endOfMonth using cal.ser(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30) for 28 day of Feb and 31Days of the month?. Is there any way it will automatically get days of the month rather than specifying static value?

Comment: You can use the ```getActualMinimum``` and ```getActualMaximum``` to get the first day and last day. 
I edited my answer in this way

Comment: Thanks Millions. you saved me

Comment: @SatTalk May I ask you to validate my answer in order to close your question ? Thanks !

Comment: sorry for late reply.. accepted answer